# How to fit object to camera in threejs using OrthographicCamera?

Tags: three.js

I find many solution but it could only appply to PerspectiveCamera because OrthographicCamera has no fov.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Have you tried something already with `THREE.OrthographicCamera()`?

Comment: Of course，but all solutions need to set fov——it is used for  PerspectiveCamera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @gaitat said, with `THREE.OrthographicCamera` you need to adjust it's frustum dimensions to fit the size of an object you want to zoom in.

Straightforward thing to do would be to use `geometry.boundingSphere` and set camera `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `up` based on that. The easier thing to do would be to use `camera.zoom` to do the work, i.e.

```
// center camera on the object (ellipse in this case)
var boundingSphere = ellipse.geometry.boundingSphere

// aspect equals window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
if( aspect > 1.0 )
{
    // if view is wider than it is tall, zoom to fit height
    camera.zoom = viewHeight / ( boundingSphere.radius * 2 )
}
else
{
    // if view is taller than it is wide, zoom to fit width
    camera.zoom = viewWidth / ( boundingSphere.radius * 2 )
}

// Don't forget this
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
```

This will set the zoom level to be such that object (ellipse in this case) fits exactly your camera's frustum.

**However**, you will also have to center the camera on the object by either:

- rotating the camera to point to the boundingSphere center
- translating the camera so that the boundingSphere center ends up on the camera's frustum axis

Since translating the camera is easier thing to do of the two, and `THREE.OrthographicCamera` is mostly used to show 2D representation of your scene (i.e. for UI or some other things that take place on a plane parallel to the camera), here is the code to do just that:

```
camera.position.copy(boundingSphere.center)
// The number here is more or less arbitrary
// as long as all objects that need to be visible
// end up within the frustum
camera.position.z = 15
```

This assumes that your objects are in some plane parallel to XY plane and that the camera is positioned to look parallel to Z-axis (as it is by default).

Here is codepen that shows small grid and an ellipse in XY plane. On mouse down camera will zoom to the ellipse, and on mouse up it will come back to it's original state:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJEzew

Comment: I tried to update view to fit with the object but it was wrong solution. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the Orthographic camera includes the `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` frustum planes that actually define the bounds of your camera. So you need to match the bounding box of your object to the bounds of your camera. The length of the `x-axis` bounding box of your object should be less or equal to `right-left` and the length of the `y-axis` bounding box of your object should be less or equal to `bottom-top`.

If you scale your object by the ratio of these lengths, the object should fit in your camera.